# How to start fabric-ca server with tls enabled

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I tried to start the fabric-ca server with tls enabled. Done changing the tls enabled to true in fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file. Also tried starting the fabric-ca-server with the following commands:

```
fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0/ca/ca.org0-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0/ca/8dbc8fbc5ee4496541a5cf71dac87672c492e1820f30993cbe3d4f7109e50a91_sk -b admin:adminpw
```

With peer cert and key files:

```
fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw --tls.enabled --tls.certfile /root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0/peers/peer2.org0/tls/server.crt --tls.keyfile /root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0/peers/peer2.org0/tls/server.key
```

But getting the following error:

```
Error: read ../github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/server: is a directory
```

I already set the paths:

```
FABRIC_CA_HOME=../github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/server
```

Comment: By sure it is not the error, but I find strange that `FABRIC_CA_HOME` is a relative path. Try to set its absolute path (the one containing `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml`). the you can set your `tls.certfile` and `tls.certfile` relative to your `FABRIC_CA_HOME`, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set tls.certfile and tls.keyfile in the environment variables of the fabric-ca server while you have enabled tls to true. But the error is not because of that but because of the incorrect mapping of the fabric-ca directory which have the certificate and key file.

Comment: Now given all the environment variables and started the fabric-ca-server successfully with tls enabled. I need to enroll the identities. But i am confused with the certificates to be provided. Can you please help on how to enroll the admin and how to register and enroll the users with tls enabled. Please reply asap

Comment: https://github.com/aldredb/bring-your-own-orderer/blob/master/create_crypto.sh  Check this repo for help regarding tls as in this two CAs are used for each org one is fabric-ca and other is tlsca. You can do the same for registering and enrolling certs.

Comment: I have started my server natively. So can you say me the way to enroll and register identities with tls enabled in the server running natively

Comment: You just have to set different msp paths for different identities and there is nothing different in running server natively so you can definitely follow that repo to enroll and register identities. It actually start an instance of tlsca inside that fabric-ca only.